# How to prove two cross ratios on a triangle are equal using collinearity (Geometry for College Students 3C.2)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to solve two related problems, 3C.2 and 3C.3, for a homework assignment but find myself stuck. They are from the 2nd edition Geometry for College Students by Martin Isaacs. Since they include a diagram I included a picture. The problems are as follows with the relevant hint that it gives below: [3C.2 and 3C.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaVUB.png)

My textbook defines cross ratio for four points as $cr(A,B,C,D)=\frac{AC\cdot BD}{AD\cdot BC}$ and defines $cr(A,B,C,D)=cr(W,X,Y,Z)$ when the lines AW, BX, CY, and DZ all meet at single point.

For what I've tried, I started with 3C.2 using the definition of cross ratios. But not matter what I tried and how I played the the triangle, I could not figure out how to get $\frac{AZ\cdot YC}{AC\cdot YZ}=\frac{AX\cdot WB}{AB\cdot WX}$

I realized that it might be better to see if WY, XZ, and BC meet at a single point and use that to show that $cr(A,Y,Z,C)=cr(A, W, X, B)$. After drawing it out I realized that they did all meet at a point. It was then that I realized that I'd created the conditions for 3C.3.

I thought if I was able to prove that 3C.3 I could then use it to prove 3C.2. However this is where I get stuck. I felt that if I used the hint, I can do two smaller proofs. In one I can assume $T=C$ and get the correct solution rather easily. Then I could do $T \neq C$ and look for a contradiction.

Visually if $T\neq C$, then R is not on BC, and A, P, and Q are no longer all collinear so I have a contradiction with the problem setup. However I can only draw a picture of this for a single case, which is not a proof!

Even though I can see why the statement in both problems is true, I am stuck on turning it into a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

Extend line $AQP$ to meet $BC$ at $H$. Then we have:
$$
cr(A,Y,Z,C)=cr(A,Q,P,H)
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
cr(A,W,X,B)=cr(A,Q,P,H),
$$
because lines $YQ$, $ZP$, $CH$ are concurrent
and lines $WQ$, $XP$, $BH$ are concurrent.
That proves 3C.2. For 3C.3 you can follow the hint given in the text.